# Can (how do) I configure a Draytek Vigor 2860n as a wireless extension to my home broadband AP?

Tags: router, wireless-access-point, draytek

I have a Windows 10 PC which doesn't have a WiFi adapter but only Ethernet.

I do, however, have a spare Draytek Vigor 2860n router, the idea I have being to connect from PC to router via Ethernet cable *IF* I can get Internet access wirelessly from the router (because the router is well away from my master socket and I don't want to trail 20 metres of Ethernet cable around the house !!).

So my question is: the 2860n can scan my broadband AP OK, but can the router be configured to connect to that AP **wirelessly** (i.e. a wireless AP repeater) ? Sure, I can trail a long cable between WAN ports, or I can buy a mains extender, but I'm trying to avoid that if possible ?

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

So I asked this question of Draytek Support themselves, who were adamant on the telephone that it couldn't be done.

They then emailed me back some hours later and apologised, claiming they hadn't understood my question !!

Here's how you do it:

[Draytek Support Video](https://www.draytek.co.uk/information/our-technology/wireless-wan-wifi)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community
I'm sorry? I'm not quite sure how you want me to improve the answer ? The link I posted came directly from Draytek themselves, so what types of other citations or documentation are you suggesting ? Why might others disagree with an answer that comes straight from the manufacturer of the product ?